# How to read attribute from HDF5 file?

Tags: java, hdf5

I am using libraries provided by `ch.systemsx.cisd.hdf5.HDF5Factory(JHDF5)` for reading an HDF5 file. Their documentation link is not working as well and I do not know whom to approach to get a solution for this.

Does anyone here know how to read attribute value from HDF5 file using above java libraries ?

Comment: This link may help you: https://www.hdfgroup.org/ftp/HDF5/hdf-java/current/src/unpacked/examples/groups/H5Ex_G_Traverse.java

Answer (score 1):

After lot of trial and error found a solution for this. Please find code below to read attribute value from HDF5 file.

> nwbFile - Name of HDF5 file (It should be opened).
>   attributeName: Name of the attribute.
>   path - path of the Node in file whose attribute needs to be read.

```
DataFormat dataset = (Dataset) FileFormat.findObject(nwbFile, path);
List<Attribute> attributes = dataset.getMetadata();
for(Attribute a : attributes)
{
    if(a.getName().equals(attributeName))
    {
        Object obj = a.getValue();
        if (obj instanceof double[])
        {
            Double d = ((double[]) obj)[0];
            return d.toString();
        }
        else if (obj instanceof String[])
        { 
             return ((String[]) obj)[0];
        }
    }
}
```